# why the Session is killing automatically when executing a query

Tags: postgresql-9.3

I have a table called table1 which is having 1 GB size. When am  trying  to extracting data from table into CSV file the session is killing by automatically.
Getting error message like session has been killed.

Can anyone help me out of this issue why this is happened.

Query: `select * from table1 where col_name ilike 'ra%';`

Comment: how do tiy know it is killed? see some exception? timeout?

Comment: What is error message you get? (**[Edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: Hint: use `\copy` in `psql`

Comment: Yes I tried by using \copy or psql command's but it's showing message like session has been killed

Comment: `terminated`? `canceled`?.. `due to timeout`? `by administrator`, `confict with recovery`??.. POST the exact message